# SQL average number of requests per user over time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (Requests) with the following fields:

id, requestType, userEmail, date

I want to find the average number of requests per user over a given period (i.e. over the last month). Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like SUM feature will work. Might be a little slow.

```
SELECT SUM(requestType) FROM Requests WHERE `userEmail` = `userEmail` and `date` BETWEEN `first-date YYYY-MM-DD` AND `second-date YYYY-MM-DD`;
```

[SQL SUM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

I would also recommend, if you have a lot of request, to have one row per user per day and just update the request total for that user.

Edit: If you want the last 30 days something like this query should work. It worked on my test table.

```
 SELECT SUM(requestType) FROM Requests WHERE `userEmail` = `userEmail` and `date`BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND curdate();
```

Comment: Sorry--to clarify, I want the average number of requests per user (over the last month) regardless of the request type

Comment: This does add together all the requestType for a user. It does not matter the type. Specifically, it gives you a whole number.

Comment: Hm..for some reason I wasn't getting the result I wanted. Anyway, here's what I ended up doing: select avg(myCount) as Events from 
(
select count(*) as myCount from Requests where date >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 30 day) group by email
) newTable

Comment: Glad you got the results you needed. -D